# Developing asp.net mvc applications as a team?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, methodology

I don't know if this has been discussed.

Let's say you are in a three developer team. How would you share:

- models - views - controllers
- by controllers
- by use cases
- something else?

Maybe someone says this has nothing to do with asp.net mvc but I think it affects somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it by story. But by far the best way is have 2 developers work on the same story. Working together across the whole architecture. They can share the tasks as they are needed, creating the view or the model or the stored procs, and tables etc. There will be some stepping on toes but at those times they can pair program.
Try to think of the 'team' doing a story. Rather than a single developer, and if they all work on the same story at the same time, the development should flow at a cracking pace.
As Kieron says, you need a ten minute design meeting with the whole team, to decide how its going to hang together.

Answer (score 2):

We break it up like this:

Team A:

- Views
- CSS
- JavaScript

Team B:

- Controllers
- Models
- Database

We use Mind Mapping applications to work out what Controllers and Views we need first, so the whole team knows how to tie things together.

It's worked brilliantly for us, increased our productivity substantionally.

Answer (score 1):

By use case or task.  Helps spread the knowledge about the entire process around.